# Is their a formula for calculating Future Value of a series of payments with monthly deposit but annual compounding?

Tags: calculation

Exactly as the title suggests

Is there a formula for the future value of monthly payments with annual compounding?

Perhaps approximating the outcome achieved by the following calculator?

https://www.bankrate.com/calculators/savings/compound-savings-calculator-tool.aspx

With frequency set to monthly and compounding set to annually?

Even an approach to interpolating the result would be helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nominal rate annually compounded is equivalent to the effective annual rate.

See [Effective interest rate calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation)

Therefore the monthly rate `m` is calculated by

```
m = (1 + r)^(1/12) - 1
```

The [future value of an annuity-due](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/) (meaning payment at period start) is

```
fv = (d (1 + m) ((1 + m)^n - 1))/m
```

where

```
d is the payment
m is the monthly rate
n is the number of months
```

For example

```
with 10% nominal interest compounded annually

effective annual rate, r = 0.1

monthly rate, m = (1 + r)^(1/12) - 1 = 0.00797414

future value paying d = 100 monthly over n = 12 months

fv = (d (1 + m) ((1 + m)^n - 1))/m = 1264.05
```

A starting amount `a = 1000` can be added as `a (1 + m)^n = 1100`

giving a total of 2364.05 as confirmed by the Bankrate calculator.

[image]

Comment: would the same formulaic approach apply if the interest was compounde monthly but the payment made annually (or quarterly)?

Comment: @BarryHamilton Hi. If you are starting with a nominal annual rate compounded monthly,`i`, you can convert it to the effective monthly rate, `m`, by `m = i/12`.  Otherwise, for instance if `i` is a nominal annual rate compounded *quarterly*, first convert to an effective annual rate, `r`,  by the formula [**in this link**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) : `r = (1 + i/n)^n - 1` .  Then you can calculate the monthly rate, or whatever rate is required, by `m = (1 + r)^(1/n) - 1`.